# How to make the file upload button on center

Tags: javascript

Cleck my site
https://webpconverterio.blogspot.com/
How to make the file upload button on center in mobile view
[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDe8m.jpg)

Comment: I submitted an answer below, but this should be tagged as CSS and you should modify the question to show code rather than link and images. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve this with Javascript? This may be tagged wrong, looking at your website I was able to center the form by adding one simple line to the CSS styles:

```
[type=file] {
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 200px; /* this is causing you to add 200px of margin  on the left /*
}
```

You can either remove that from the styles if you don't need it, or target mobile devices with the following css:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   [type=file] {
     margin: 20px 0;
     margin-left: 0;
   }
}
```

Note, I haven't tested that css so you may need to modify it a bit. You can take a look here for adding media queries to your css styles to target different devices: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type=file] {
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

the problem is here, you should make it **responsive** or use **flex display** (flex make it very easy).

however you can now add this to your css and make it right.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  input[type=file] {
    margin: 20px 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
}
```